C# WPF - How to update all items in a List based on one of them changing, and make the bindings work?
I am trying to make a WPF application where I have a list of items (in this case Walls) in a DataGrid, and I want to visualize the geometry of the items (Walls). I have attached an image below.
Basically, my items are Walls which have a height and a length. The walls are supposed to be stacked on top of each other, like in the image below. (At initialization they are neatly stacked, only because that is how I have manually initialized my list.)
MainWindow
The Main Window that you see above is made of 3 columns:
0 - The left column has a stackpanel which contains the DataGrid.
1 - The middle column has an ItemsControl, with the ItemsPanelTemplate set to a canvas. The big red square shows the outline of the canvas, as a temporary guide.
2 - The right column is irrelevant/unused for now.
The code below shows how the ItemsControl/Canvas is set up. Basically I visualize the Walls as borders, with a specific size and position based on the input. I could use rectangles as well, but have not stumbled upon any significant pros/cons.
<ItemsControl Grid.Column="1" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding Walls, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas Background="IndianRed"
                    Margin="20"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border Width="{Binding XLength}"
                    Height="{Binding YHeight}"
                    Background="#CCCCCC"
                    BorderBrush="Black"
                    BorderThickness="1">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Floor}"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                           VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding XPos}"/>
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding YPos}"/>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</ItemsControl>

Here is a picture of my Solution Explorer for a quick overview:
Solution Explorer
The Walls are defined by this class:
Basically, Height and Length are the IRL dimensions of the wall. I use a scale of 50 to get XLength and YHeight, which is the size of the border that represents weach wall. Similarly, each wall has a XPos and YPos with the same scale applied to it, which defines its position on the canvas.
public class Wall : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private static int _scale = 50;

    private string _floor; //Just a string of text displayed on each Border
    private double _height; //Height of wall IRL
    private double _length; //Lenght of wall IRL
    private double _xPos; //Horizonal position on canvas (Canvas.Left)
    private double _yPos; //Vertical position on canvas (Canvas.Top)
    private double _xLength; //Width of Border on canvas (IRL Length * Scale)
    private double _yHeight; //Height of Border on canvas (IRL Height * Scale)

    public string Floor
    {
        get { return _floor; }
        set { _floor = value; }
    }

    public double Height
    {
        get { return _height; }
        set 
        { 
            _height = value;
            _yHeight = value*_scale;
            OnPropertyChanged("YHeight");
        }
    }

    public double Length
    {
        get { return _length; }
        set 
        { 
            _length = value;
            _xLength = value*_scale;
            OnPropertyChanged("XLength");
        }
    }

    public double XPos
    {
        get { return _xPos; }
        set { _xPos = value; }
    }

    public double YPos
    {
        get { return _yPos; }
        set { _yPos = value; }
    }

    public double XLength
    {
        get { return _xLength; }
        set { _xLength = Length * _scale; }
    }

    public double YHeight
    {
        get { return _yHeight; }
        set { _yHeight = Height * _scale; }
    }
    
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}

The variables of the Wall are described in this picture:
Description of XLength, YHeight, XPos, YPos
In the properties for XLength and YHeight I have successfully applied some simple formulas to make the length and height follow along. For instance, when I change a bunch of values in the DataGrid, I can get something like this:
MainWindow when values in DataGrid changed
However, I would like the YPos property to change, so that the walls are always stacked on top of each other. So if I change the height of floor 4, all the walls below it need to change their YPos value, and so on. I have not succeeded in this, and am asking for your help!
I tried to make a method which does something along the lines of this:
public void OrderWalls()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < _walls.Count; i++)
    {
        Walls[i].YPos = Walls[i-1].YPos + Walls[i].YHeight;
    }
}

But I can't quite wrap my head around how I would apply the method within the property of YPos. Or am I going about it all wrong? Any help is appreciated!
Here is my ViewModel, and the codebehind of my Main Window:
public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<Wall> _walls;

    public ObservableCollection<Wall> Walls
    {
        get { return _walls; }
        set 
        { 
            _walls = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public void OrderWalls()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < _walls.Count; i++)
        {
            Walls[i].YPos = Walls[i-1].YPos + Walls[i].YHeight;
        }
    }

    public MainWindowViewModel() 
    {
        Walls = new ObservableCollection<Wall>();

        Walls.Add(new Wall { Floor = "Floor 4", Height = 3, Length = 6, YPos = 50, XPos = 50 });
        Walls.Add(new Wall { Floor = "Floor 3", Height = 3, Length = 6, YPos = 200, XPos = 50 });
        Walls.Add(new Wall { Floor = "Floor 2", Height = 3, Length = 6, YPos = 350, XPos = 50 });
        Walls.Add(new Wall { Floor = "Floor 1", Height = 3, Length = 6, YPos = 500, XPos = 50 });
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        MainWindowViewModel viewModel = new MainWindowViewModel();
        this.DataContext = viewModel;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}


Edit related to comment made to @BionicCode on July 11th:
So I have spent quite a bit of time trying to implement your answer. You are using a lot of functions that I previously didn't know about, so I had to do some research. I think I understand most of it by now, but I am definitely not there yet.
I tried to implement your suggestions into my program, but without the "orientation" property, since I just want to keep it vertical for now (trying not to overwhelm myself), and also without the "IsArrangeItemEnabled", since I want it to always arrange. So I have not exactly copied down your code. I hope I haven't broken any of the intended functionality in doing so..
Upon initialization of the program, all the YPos are calculated correctly. However when i change the values in the DataGrid, the YPos properties don't get updated, and i can't figure out why.
I am trying to understand the system by which all the functions call each other, and I can't quite figure out what is supposed to make the YPos properties update. I notice in WallCollection.cs we have a method OnSizeChanged, which doesn't get used anywhere. Could this be the cause?
I think it would help me a lot if you could elaborate a bit on the functions used in WallCollection.cs and how they relate to each other. I am particularly confused about the StartOberveSizeChanges and StopObserveSizeChanges, and Dictionary/indexmap. If you don't have the time I completely understand :)
WallCollection.cs
public class WallCollection : ObservableCollection<Wall>
{
    public WallCollection() { }
    private readonly Dictionary<Wall, int> indexMap = new();

    protected override void SetItem(int index, Wall item)
    {
        base.SetItem(index, item);
        AddItemInternal(index, item);
    }

    protected override void InsertItem(int index, Wall item)
    {
        base.InsertItem(index, item);
        AddItemInternal(index, item);
    }

    private void AddItemInternal(int index, Wall item)
    {
        if (!this.indexMap.ContainsKey(item))
        {
            StartObservingSizeChanges(item);
        }
        InitializeWallPosition(index, item);
    }

    private void InitializeWallPosition(int index, Wall item)
    {
        if (index > 0 && item is not null && double.IsInfinity(item.YPos))
        {
            Wall previousWall = this.Items[index - 1];
            item.YPos = previousWall.YPos + previousWall.YHeight;
        }
    }

    private void StartObservingSizeChanges(Wall item)
    {
        WeakEventManager<Wall, WallSizeChangedEventArgs>.AddHandler(item, nameof(Wall.SizeChanged), OnWallSizeChanged);
    }

    private void OnWallSizeChanged(object? sender, WallSizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var changedWall = (Wall)sender;
        ArrangeWalls(changedWall, e.HasHeightChanged, e.HeightChange);
    }

    private void ArrangeWalls(Wall? changedWall, bool hasHeightChanged, double heightChange)
    {
        if (hasHeightChanged)
        {
            ArrangeItemsVertically(changedWall, heightChange);
        }
    }

    private void ArrangeItemsVertically(Wall changedWall, double change)
    {
        if (!this.indexMap.TryGetValue(changedWall, out int indexOfChangedWall))
        {
            return;
        }

        for (int index = indexOfChangedWall + 1; index <this.Items.Count; index++)
        {
            Wall wall = this.Items[index];
            wall.YPos += change;
        }
    }
}

WallSizeChangedEventArgs.cs
public class WallSizeChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public WallSizeChangedEventArgs(Size oldSize, Size newSize) 
    {
        this.OldSize = oldSize;
        this.NewSize = newSize;
    }

    public Size OldSize { get; }
    public Size NewSize { get; }
    public bool HasHeightChanged => this.OldSize.Height != this.NewSize.Height;
    public double HeightChange => this.NewSize.Height - this.OldSize.Height;
}

Wall.cs
public class Wall : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public Wall() 
    { 
        this.YPos = double.PositiveInfinity;
    }

    private const int _scale = 50;
    private double _height; //Height of wall IRL
    private double _length; //Lenght of wall IRL
    private double _xPos; //Horizonal position on canvas (Canvas.Left)
    private double _yPos; //Vertical position on canvas (Canvas.Top)
    
    public string Floor { get; set; }

    public double Height
    {
        get { return _height; }
        set 
        { 
            _height = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(this.YHeight));
        }
    }

    public double Length
    {
        get { return _length; }
        set 
        { 
            _length = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(this.XLength));
        }
    }

    public double XPos
    {
        get { return _xPos; }
        set 
        { 
            _xPos = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public double YPos
    {
        get { return _yPos; }
        set 
        { 
            _yPos = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public double XLength => this.Length * _scale;

    public double YHeight => this.Height * _scale;
    
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged; //Unchanged
    public event EventHandler<WallSizeChangedEventArgs>? SizeChanged; //New
    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null) //Unchanged
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }

    protected virtual void OnSizeChanged(Size oldSize, Size newSize)
       => this.SizeChanged?.Invoke(this, new WallSizeChangedEventArgs(oldSize, newSize));
}

MainWindowViewModel.cs
public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<Wall> Walls { get; }
    public MainWindowViewModel() 
    {
        Walls = new WallCollection()
        {
            new Wall { Floor = "Floor 4", Height = 3, Length = 6, YPos = 50, XPos = 50 },
            new Wall { Floor = "Floor 3", Height = 3, Length = 6, XPos = 50 },
            new Wall { Floor = "Floor 2", Height = 3, Length = 6, XPos = 50 },
            new Wall { Floor = "Floor 1", Height = 3, Length = 6, XPos = 50 }
        };
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}


You have to calculate the y position which is the sum of the heights of the floors below the current floor.  Floor 1 = 0, Floor 2 = 0 + 3, Floor 3 = 0 + 3 + 1, Floor 4 = 0 + 3 + 1 + 2

You could use a container, which does the math to measure/arrange its childrens and have its own bounds. Btw, all properties need to rise event.

You will need to subscribe to each Wall object's property changed event and recalculate them all for each change in height. There is nothing in your code that updates all other walls on a change. CollectionChanged only fires on Add, Remove, etc of the collection not its members.

Your code is flawed.
First, your YPos and XPos properties don't raise the PropertyChanged event. This will prevent the visual elements from updating their position on the Canvas.
Next, your calculations are wrong as well. Most important is that your index will be out of range for the first iteration as you start at index i = 0 and reference the collection with i - 1.
And then you are adding the height of the current item to the vertical position of the previous item. But you must add the previous height YHeight to the previous position YPos to get the new position of the current item:
public void OrderWalls()
{
  if (!Walls.Any())
  {
    return;
  }

  for (int i = 1; i < _walls.Count; i++)
  {
    // This line will throw an IndexOutOfRangeException 
    // because in the first iteration 'index = i -1' results in 'index == -1'
    //Walls[i].YPos = Walls[i-1].YPos + Walls[i].YHeight;

    // Naming the elements usually visualizes what you are doing to help 
    // identifying logical and typing errors
    Wall currentWall = Walls[i];
    Wall previousWall = Walls[i - 1];
    currentWall.YPos = previousWall.YPos + previousWall.YHeight;
  }
}

However, this algorithm can be significantly improved in terms of performance, which becomes more relevant the more items the collection contains. Since the height change is known, you can use it to avoid the complete iteration of the collection. The fact that preceding items are not affected by height changes allows us to skip them.
Then we can simply offset the vertical position by the height change. The Wall class must notify about its size change so that the owner of the Wall items can rearrange the objects. For this reason, the Wall class must implement a SizeChanged event.
You should move all the related logic to a dedicated class. For example, you could create a custom WallCollection that listens to the Wall.SizedChanged event to rearrange the items. You can encpasulate the behavior into any class, but this class must have a reference to the collection and it must track the collection for add/remove changes in order to register/unregister the SizeChanged event handlers. It's easier to have this logic directly in the specialized collection, that's why I choose the WallCollection.
WallSizeChangedEventArgs.cs
Event data to provide details about the changes to the observer.
public class WallSizeChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
  public WallSizeChangedEventArgs(Size oldSize, Size newSize)
  {
    this.OldSize = oldSize;
    this.NewSize = newSize;
  }

  public Size OldSize { get; }
  public Size NewSize { get; }
  public bool HasHeightChanged => this.OldSize.Height != this.NewSize.Height;
  public bool HasWidthChanged => this.OldSize.Width != this.NewSize.Width;
  public double HeightChange => this.NewSize.Height - this.OldSize.Height;
  public double WidthChange => this.NewSize.Width - this.OldSize.Width;
}

Wall.cs
See comments to learn about the fixes.
public class Wall : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public Wall()
  {
    // Set the default. If the YPos value is left with this default
    // then the WallCollection will automatically stack items
    // with a gap of zero between the Wall items. Updating YPos will keep the gap at zero.
    // If the default is overwritten e.g. with 100, and this value would create a gap of e.g. 30
    // between the current and the preceding Wall item, then WallCollection will now update the YPos
    // by simply adding the offset. This way the vertical margin will always remain the same (30).
    this.YPos = double.PositiveInfinity;
  }

  // Introduce an event to notify about changes and make information about change details,
  // like the actual change value, available.
  // This helps to implement the re-arrange algorithm more efficiently
  // as we can now avoid the complete iteration of the collection.
  public event EventHandler<WallSizeChangedEventArgs>? SizeChanged;

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

  // Prefer const over static (or static readonly)
  private const int Scale = 50;

  private double _height; //Height of wall IRL
  private double _length; //Lenght of wall IRL
  private double _xPos; //Horizonal position on canvas (Canvas.Left)
  private double _yPos; //Vertical position on canvas (Canvas.Top)

  // If this property doesn't raise the PropertyChanged event make it an auto-property
  public string Floor { get; set; }

  public double Height
  {
    get => _height;
    set
    {
      // We will only report the scaled size
      double oldHeight = this.YHeight;

      _height = value;

      // Avoid duplicate formula definition. Either execute from property setter (recommended) or move to method
      //_yHeight = value * Scale;

      // Use 'nameof' instead of magic strings for robustness. 
      //OnPropertyChanged("YHeight");
      OnPropertyChanged(nameof(this.YHeight));

      // We will only report the scaled size
      OnSizeChanged(new Size(this.XLength, oldHeight), new Size(this.XLength, this.YHeight));
    }
  }

  public double Length
  {
    get { return _length; }
    set
    {
      // We will only report the scaled size
      double oldWidth = this.XLength;

      _length = value;

      // Avoid duplicate formula definition. Either execute from property setter (recommended) or move to method
      //_xLength = value * Scale;

      // Use 'nameof' instead of magic strings for robustness and IDE support to avoid typos or enable symbol renaming. 
      //OnPropertyChanged("XLength");
      OnPropertyChanged(nameof(this.XLength));

      // We will only report the scaled size
      OnSizeChanged(new Size(oldWidth, this.YHeight), new Size(this.XLength, this.YHeight));
    }
  }

  // This property must raise the PropertyChanged event
  // to trigger the repositioning on the Canvas via data binding!
  public double XPos
  {
    get => _xPos;
    set
    {
      _xPos = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  // This property must raise the PropertyChanged event
  // to trigger the repositioning on the Canvas via data binding!
  public double YPos
  {
    get => _yPos;
    set
    {
      _yPos = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  // The setter is redundant as it discards the set value. Instead implement property as computed property.
  //
  // Width of Border on canvas (IRL Length * Scale)
  public double XLength => this.Length * Scale;
  //{
  //  get { return _xLength; }
  //
  //  // This setter is redundant as it discards the set value. Instead implement property as computed property
  //  set { _xLength = Length * Scale; }
  //}

  // The setter is redundant as it discards the set value. Instead implement property as computed property.
  //
  // Height of Border on canvas (IRL Height * Scale)
  public double YHeight => this.Height * Scale;
  //{
  //  get { return _yHeight; }

  //  // This setter is redundant as it discards the set value. Instead implement property as computed property
  //  set { _yHeight = Height * Scale; }
  //}

  protected virtual void OnSizeChanged(Size oldSize, Size newSize)
    => this.SizeChanged?.Invoke(this, new WallSizeChangedEventArgs(oldSize, newSize));

  protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}

WallCollection.cs
This collection will also automatically stack each added item overriding the initial YPos value if it is double.PositiveInfinity.
public class WallCollection : ObservableCollection<Wall>
{
  public WallCollection()
  { }

  public WallCollection(IEnumerable<Wall> collection) : base(collection)
  { }

  public WallCollection(List<Wall> list) : base(list)
  { }

  protected override void SetItem(int index, Wall item)
  {
    CheckReentrancy();

    // In case the index exists, the item will be replaced.
    // Therefore, we have to unhook all event handlers 
    // from the replaced item.
    RemoveItemInternal(index);

    // Add/replace the item
    base.SetItem(index, item);

    // Store the index in a hash table for fast lookup
    AddItemInternal(index, item);
  }

  protected override void InsertItem(int index, Wall item)
  {
    // Add the item
    base.InsertItem(index, item);

    // Store the index in a hash table for fast lookup
    AddItemInternal(index, item);
  }

  protected override void RemoveItem(int index)
    => RemoveItemInternal(index);

  protected override void ClearItems()
  {
    // Call CheckReentrancy to prevent this collection from being modifed while CollectionChanged event is raised.
    // The OnCollectionChanged implementation usually calls BlockReentrancy().
    // This is important as you want to prevent CollectionChanged event handlers to modify the collection
    // *before* all listeners have been notified (about the exact same state). 
    // You don't want that a "item added" ColectionChanged event becomes obsolete
    // because event handler A has e.g. removed the new item before event handler B could handle it.
    // Event handler B would still get the original notification about an added item.
    // But because event handler A has modified the collection, the event now reports an invalid state to event handler B.
    // This introduces a high potential for bugs. To avoid this, the collection is locked during CollectionChanged events.
    // If OnCollectionChanged has called BlockReentrancy() then calling CheckReentrancy()
    // from a modifying method will throw an exception until the bock has been lifted (all event handlers have been executed).
    // CheckReentrancy is usually called by the base methods SetItem(), InserItem(), RemoveItem() and ClearItems().
    // Because we have to unregister SizeChanged event handlers for each individual item
    // we have to perform the cleanup before manually clearing the collection.
    // We therefore don't invoke the base implementation of ClearItems() which is why we have to call CheckReentrancy by ourselves.
    CheckReentrancy();

    for (int index = this.Count - 1; index >= 0; index--)
    {
      RemoveItemInternal(index);
    }

    this.indexMap.Clear();
    OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(this.Count)));
    OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Binding.IndexerName)));

    // This base method of ObservableCollection will internally call BlockReentrancy()
    // to lock this collection for modifications during the event execution
    OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
  }

  private void AddItemInternal(int index, Wall item)
  {
    if (!this.indexMap.ContainsKey(item))
    {
      this.indexMap.Add(item, index);
      StartObserveSizeChanges(item);
    }

    // Auto align the added Wall
    InitializeVerticalWallPosition(index, item);
  }

  private void RemoveItemInternal(int index)
  {
    Wall removedItem = this[index];
    base.RemoveItem(index);
    StopObserveSizeChanges(removedItem);
    _ = this.indexMap.Remove(removedItem);
  }

  private void InitializeVerticalWallPosition(int index, Wall item)
  {
    // Only arrange when:
    if (index > 0  // item is not the first
        && item is not null
        && double.IsInfinity(item.YPos)) // item has no explicit vertical position assigned (the default YPos value is double.PositiveInfinity)
    {
      Wall previousWall = this.Items[index - 1];
      item.YPos = previousWall.YPos + previousWall.YHeight;

      ArrangeWalls(item, true, item.YHeight);
    }
  }

  private void StartObserveSizeChanges(Wall item)
  {
    // In case the items live longer than this collection (and the collection is not cleared before disregarded),
    // we must use a WeakEventManager to avoid a leak.
    WeakEventManager<Wall, WallSizeChangedEventArgs>.AddHandler(item, nameof(Wall.SizeChanged), OnWallSizeChanged);
  }

  private void StopObserveSizeChanges(Wall item)
  {
    // In case the items live longer than this collection (and the collection is not cleared before disregarded),
    // we must use a WeakEventManager to avoid a leak.
    WeakEventManager<Wall, WallSizeChangedEventArgs>.RemoveHandler(item, nameof(Wall.SizeChanged), OnWallSizeChanged);
  }

  // When a wall has changed its YHeight we must rearrange all succeeding Wall items.
  // A changing height means that the YPos offset of all succedding items has to be adjusted.
  private void OnWallSizeChanged(object? sender, WallSizeChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    var changedWall = (Wall)sender;
    ArrangeWalls(changedWall, e.HasHeightChanged, e.HeightChange);
  }

  private void ArrangeWalls(Wall? changedWall, bool hasHeightChanged, double heightChange)
  {
    if (hasHeightChanged)
    {
      ArrangeItemsVertically(changedWall, heightChange);
    }
  }

  private void ArrangeItemsVertically(Wall changedWall, double change)
  {
    // If  there wasn't the Dictionary we would have to call IndexOf(changedWall) to get the current index.
    // And then increment the index to get the succeeding Wall items.
    // This is a O(n) operation while querying the Dictionary is O(1). This means the perfomance is not depedeing on the size of collection.
    // We will always get the index immediately.
    if (!this.indexMap.TryGetValue(changedWall, out int indexOfChangedWall))
    {
      return;
    }

    // Start from the changed item to improve the perfromance.
    // The preceding items are not affected by the size change of the current item.
    for (int index = indexOfChangedWall + 1; index < this.Items.Count; index++)
    {
      Wall wall = this.Items[index];

      // For example, if the heigth of Wall A has changed by +10 or -20
      // then me must vertically offset all succeeding Wall items by +10 or -20
      wall.YPos += change;
    }
  }

  // The map that stores the index of each Wall for fast lookup.
  // This is to avoid IndexOf calls as this will perform bad for big collections.
  private readonly Dictionary<Wall, int> indexMap = new();
}

MainWindowViewModel.cs
public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  // A binding source collection should always be 
  // a readonly property that returns an ObservableCollection.
  public WallCollection Walls { get; }

  public MainWindowViewModel()
  {
    // Only set the YPos of the first item. 
    // The WallCollection will stack them properly. 
    // If you want to start at YPos == 0 then you don't even have 
    // to set the YPos of the first item. 
    // Any explicit YPos value set will have precedence over the 
    // calculated arrangement of the WallCollection.
    Walls = new WallCollection()
    {
      new Wall { Floor = "Floor 4", Height = 3, Length = 6, YPos = 50, XPos = 50 },
      new Wall { Floor = "Floor 3", Height = 3, Length = 6, XPos = 50 },
      new Wall { Floor = "Floor 2", Height = 3, Length = 6, XPos = 50 },
      new Wall { Floor = "Floor 1", Height = 3, Length = 6, XPos = 50 }
    };
  }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
  protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
  {
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
  }
}


Thank you very much for this helpful and thorough answer. It is very appreciated. I learned more things than I expected :-)

Thank you very much for your feedback and appreciation. I'm happy you found this answer helpful. Thanks!

Hey. Thanks again for your time. I tried implementing your suggestions, and also have some follow up questions. I hope you can find some time to take a look.
See the edit to my post

Hey, no problem. Sorry for the additional complexity of the answer. The extra functionality was really easy to implement without additional effort. I thought it would make the functionality of the collection rounder. But I understand that it distracts from the essentials especially if you are trying to understand the fundamentals of the implementation.

I have to apologize and I hope I didn't cause you too many headaches. I will rework the implementation and add some annotations that may help you to understand the implementation details better. Based on this you can ask more focused questions to get more specific answers.

Alright I have updated the code: I have removed everything you were not asking for and I have added and extended comments to explain the why and what. I recommend to read through the code from top. The bug you were reporting was indeed related to the fact that OnSizeChanged was never called. It's now called from the Height  and Length properties. But the reported size will be based on the scaled dimensions YHeight and XLength. If you want to report both sizes (scaled and original) you can extend the SizeChangedEventArgs to add related properties (the scale factor could be sufficient).

Thanks for getting back to me so quickly!
Thank you for adding the extra comments. I understand some of the intended functionalities better now :)
However, the YPos doesn't seem to be updating. The walls are not stacking at least..
I have pretty much copied down your code. I notice in Wall.cs in the setter's for Height and Length: when calling OnSizeChanged(oldSize,newSize), are we not putting the same size twice, since we say oldHeight = this.YHeight. At the point where OnSizeChanged is executed, will this.Yheight be the old or the new height?

Also, a bit of a side question. Is there a way I can follow the XPos,YPos,etc. for each Wall while the program is running, and I am changing values in the DataGrid etc. I tried implementing some sort of foreach(Wall wall in Walls){Console.WriteLine(Walls[i].YPos)}, but I can't seem to reach the Walls collection from anywhere (I hope this makes sense). Is there not some (easy) way to track the properties of each item at all time, just like I would be able to in a console application?
Continued..

I know that I can put a breakpoint to be able to see items in "Locals", but I can rarely figure out where to put the breakpoint, especially with increasing complexity.

To fix the arrangement I forgot to add the items to the table. Check AddItemInternal for the change. I'm sorry for causing you these troubles. I wrote the code here on Stackoverflow. I should have tested at least the collection. I thought it was so simple but lack of attention caused me to make thath mistake. I'm sorry.

In regards to your question: you can add Debug.WriteLine to the property setter.  The Debug related code will be only compiled when in debug mode. In release mode all Debug references are ignored by the compiler. Alternatively, you can use a logger. The advantage is that you are more flexible. You can configure a logger to log to a file, database, email or console or whatever sink you provide. Also formatting the output is more flexible. There are several good loggers like Serilog or Log4net. Just do some research.

Sorry, I guess I was a little bit unspecific about the fixed code. It's the AddItemInternal method in the WallCollection class. Just added a single line.

It works now indeed!
Thank you very much for your time and your patience

You are welcome. I'm glad we got this fixed.

Sorry, have to reach b ack to you. I have updated the WallCollection.SetItem method. It was missing to handle the case of a replacement. In this case we must unhook all event handlers from the item that is being replaced. You only have to copy/update the SetItem method. I forgot to fix that. It was on my mind all the time, but then I somehow forgot about it. But the memory just came back a few minutes ago. The fix is only relevant if you replace items: wallCollectio[index] = item. Soryy about that.

Your wall objects need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged and you need to subscribe to the PropertyChangedEvent for each. Here is something to point you in the right direction.
public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<Wall> _walls;

    public ObservableCollection<Wall> Walls
    {
        get { return _walls; }
        set 
        { 
            _walls = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public void OrderWalls()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < _walls.Count; i++)
        {
            Walls[i].YPos = Walls[i-1].YPos + Walls[i].YHeight;
        }
    }

    public MainWindowViewModel() 
    {
        Walls = new ObservableCollection<Wall>();

        Walls.Add(new Wall { Floor = "Floor 4", Height = 3, Length = 6, YPos = 50, XPos = 50 });
        Walls.Add(new Wall { Floor = "Floor 3", Height = 3, Length = 6, YPos = 200, XPos = 50 });
        Walls.Add(new Wall { Floor = "Floor 2", Height = 3, Length = 6, YPos = 350, XPos = 50 });
        Walls.Add(new Wall { Floor = "Floor 1", Height = 3, Length = 6, YPos = 500, XPos = 50 });

        foreach(var wall in Walls)
        {
           wall.PropertyChanged += WallChanged; // subscribe to all changes.
        }
    }

    private void WallChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
         // May want to be selective on what changes you are worried
         // about. Only run when the height changes for instance.
         // Otherwise you could call this recursively and end up with a stack overflow.
         if(e.PropertyName == nameOf(Wall.Height))
             OrderWalls(); // Something changed update the y's.
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}


Thank your for the answer
